# Windows Driver - Unable to sign my own driver correctly

Tags: windows, cat, drive, digital-certificate, inf

I am very very beginner in windows driver development. I have written a simple DbgPrint() .sys driver.

After lots of search, I have found in x86 architecture, signing of .sys driver is optional but in x64 is mandatory. 
So I have created a certificate manually:

`makecert -r -n "CN=MyCompany" -ss MyCompanyCertStore -sr LocalMachine`

After that, I have exported it as (e.g.) GlobalSign.cer and added to my certificates list:

```
certmgr.exe -add GlobalSign.cer -c -s -r localMachine Root
certmgr.exe -add GlobalSign.cer -c -s -r localMachine TrustedPublisher
```

Then, I have putted `MyDriver1.sys` and `MyDriver1.inf` in `c:\MyDriver1` folder and created the catalog file:

```
inf2cat /driver:"c:\MyDriver1" /os:7_x64
```

And have signed it:

```
SignTool sign /s MyCompanyCertStore /n MyCompany /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll c:\MyDriver1\mydriver1.cat
```

Finished!
But when I load `MyDriver1.sys` in `OSR Driver Loader` program, it shows this error:

```
---------------------------
OSRLOADER
---------------------------
Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source.

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I dont know why.

**Note** There is only `MyDriver1.inf` entry in Security Catalog tab of catalog file and I cannot add `MyDriver1.sys` entry.

Here is the content of `MyDriver1.inf` (Originally produced by Visual Studio but I have only changed `CatalogFile=` to `CatalogFile=mydriver1.cat`)

```
;
; MyDriver1.inf
;

[Version]
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$"
Class=
ClassGuid=
Provider=
DriverVer=09/21/2017,21.4.29.698
CatalogFile=

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir = 12


[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DiskName%,,,""

[SourceDisksFiles]


[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName%=Standard,NTamd64

[Standard.NTamd64]


[Strings]
ManufacturerName=""
ClassName=""
DiskName="MyDriver1 Source Disk"
```

Answer (score 1):

KMCS doesn't use the certificate store (which is implemented is user-mode, so that makes a lot of sense...).

The root certificate of the certificate chain signging your driver has to be on of the ones listed on the [Cross-Certificates for Kernel Mode Code Signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/cross-certificates-for-kernel-mode-code-signing) page.